# Connecting Google Colab to a Docker Container Running in the Cloud

Tags: docker, google-colaboratory

Has anyone succeeded in building and using the Google Colab Docker image on a cloud VM provider like RunPod? I'm trying to connect the Colab interface to a Colab Docker container I've set up on RunPod, but I'm facing difficulties with establishing the connection. The container runs fine, but the standard approach of SSH tunneling with local port forwarding doesn't seem to work in this environment. Has anyone encountered and overcome this issue?